# Record duplication

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a form and php script that checks if a record does not exist then will insert it into the table if no same record is existing. What if two users coincidentally filling up the form and put the same record then simultaneously pressed the submit button. Is it possible that the script will still insert the records?

Comment: yes, so use db restrains such as unique-indexed fields

Comment: @Dagon What if the field is not unique? I need two fields for it to be unique. For example crew name and company.

Comment: This shouldn't happen if using transactional.

Comment: you can have a unique index on 2 fields `alter table <table_name> 
  add unique index <index_name> (crewName,company)`

Comment: @Dagon The company field can be duplicated, I can have the same company in the table. The problem is if there is the same crew name inside the company.

Comment: i understand, my above comment would solve that

Comment: @Dagon Thanks, I will try.

Comment: @Dagon Thanks, It really worked. Now I'm thinking about how can I make them unique only for those whose status is active?

Comment: may be time for transactions if you need that kind ofthing

Comment: @Dagon how can I use transaction for this? I only knew it today.

Comment: @isnotmenow will it prevent duplication without unique fields in the table?

Comment: Read more at [Database Transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) for the bigger picture. In a short, transaction means that your insert process will be atomic. When the first `insert` still working, no other same `insert` could work until the first finish.
Unique fields will prevent duplication. Can you add some more details like your schema and code in your question?. We can only guessing with your current question.

Comment: @isnotmenow thanks for the info